# Why does my javascript not get called in my onload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have my onload set to a function that calls my custom function

in the function my window should scroll to the location specified via the value after the hash - however I do not see my console log my debug text nor does the page move - what am I doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function()
    {
        scrollToLocation();
    };
function scrollToLocation()
{
    console.log("hi");
    var x = location.hash;
    console.log(x);
    $('html, body').animate(
    {
        scrollTop: x
    }, 500);
    var d = document.createElement("div");
    d.style.height = "101%";
    d.style.overflow = "hidden";
    document.body.appendChild(d);
    setTimeout(function ()
    {
        d.parentNode.removeChild(d);
    }, 10);
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: is there any other `window.onload=function(){}` statements in the page

Comment: not in my code but this is in a joomla (jumi extension) if I ctrl-u i only see mine (could it look different?)

Comment: try `$(window).load(function(){
    console.log('xxxx')
})` instead

Comment: ^ that doesn't seem to change anything (nothing in console)

Comment: Found this in the source.... <script type="text/javascript">window.addEvent('load',function(){new JCaption('img.caption');});</script> 
relevant?

Comment: that looks fine... any error in your browser console

Comment: event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. jquery.min.js:2
xxxx index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1&Itemid=101:65
3
Calling LP_setval from A onloadwff.js:78

Comment: can you try document ready instead of window load like `$(function(){ console.log('xxxx') })`

Comment: now.. what I really needed was for that to be called everytime the page loaded AND everytime the value after the # changes...

Comment: you need to look at http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/ for hash change event

Comment: Can you add an answer to this question so I can give you proper credit? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK.

I can't figure out why the window load function is not firing.

Try document ready handler instead

```
$(function(){
     scrollToLocation();
})
```

As for hashchange event is considered have a look at [this plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/)

Comment: For hashchange events I simply added this $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
  .. work ..
});